# Proof that for every $z \in \mathbb C$: $z=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(Re(u_{k}\overline z)u_{k})$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$, $n>2$ and $u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{n-1}$ are all root of unity for n. 
> Proof that for every $z \in \mathbb C$: $$z=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(Re(u_{k}\overline z)u_{k})$$

I know that $Re(u_{0})=Re(u_{1})$, $Re(u_{2})=Re(u_{3})$ etc. However then I have a problem with $n$ because I don't know anything about parity of $n$. Moreover I don't know what to use this idea even if I consider two cases: $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$. 
I thought also about $\sum _{{k=0}}^{{n-1}}e^{{\frac  {2\pi ik}{n}}}=0$ but I still do not know how to do it.

Are you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Let's see if we can get you going. Can you, using geometry, tell me the length of the projection of $z = a + bi$ onto $u_k = c + si$ (where $c$ and $s$ are sine and cosine of some number), in terms of $a, b, c,$ and $s$? Can you tell me the actual projected **vector**? [You can edit your question to add whatever you discover, and to show that you're willing to put in some effort yourself.] Does your answer bear any relationship to anything in the problem you're working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(Re(u_{k}\overline z)u_{k}) = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{u_{k}\overline z+\overline{u_{k}}z}{2}u_{k} =\frac 1n (\overline z\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k^2+z\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|u_k|^2)$$

Using a geometric argument, a geometric sum, or Newton's identities it's easy to show $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k^2=0$. Besides, $|u_k|=1$, so the result follows.